# I install meta package in R,but I can't use metaprop

Tags: r

I need to do a proportion meta-analysis, so I installed the meta package, but I can't use "metaprop", per the error below. How can I fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lEcq.png)

Comment: Did you remember to type `library(meta)` after installing it?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my "meta packages"in R,and reinstalled again, and metaprop works again!